# :after going over my text with background

Tags: html, css

I am doing a menu for a restaurant, they want to have an orange line on the last line of the menu that leads to the price. Everything is done only the orange line gets OVER by text that has a background.

Here's the link:

http://abbababba.gosuuftw.com

Thank you!

Comment: Please put your HTML & CSS code here

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Flexbox is not the best option because of its support with old browsers and a some of bugs on safari / firefox...
I would move the `:after` to `li` instead of `<p>`

```
li:after {
    content: " ";
    height: 1px; /*never use 0.x px. there is no "half pixels", NEVER.*/
    display: block;
    bottom: 0; /* make sure align to bottom */
    /* top: -13px; */
    /* background: #f26622; a line is better*/
    border-bottom: 1px dashed #f26622; /* your fancy dashed line*/
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that:

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
}

.list {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  margin-bottom: .5em;
}

.first {
  margin-right: 0.5em;
  color: #2B91AF;
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
}

.price {
  text-align: right;
  flex: 0 0 4em;
  
}

.first:after {
  content: '';
  height: 1px;
  border-bottom: dashed 1px tomato;
  flex:1;

}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Porterhouse <br/>Steak:</i>
    <i class="price">$150.00</i> 
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Baked Potato:</i>
    <i class="price"> $5.00</i> 
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Side Salad</i>
    <i class="price"> $25.00</i> 
  </li>
  <li class="list">
    <i class='first'>Soft Drink</i>
    <i class="price"> $10.00</i> 
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution by Sandrina was very good but I solved my problem using  simply

display:inline!important

Comment: no way to use !important. *never*, only when it is the only way. and this is not the case.